# How to access a WordPress website by IP address which have on shared IP address server.

Tags: wordpress, hosting, ip-address, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to access my website http://www.time-table.in by IP address only. I have hosting from digital ocean server. This is shared hosting. I have hosted more than one websites on this server. Please reply is any way to access this website by using only IP Address.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find out where on the server the website's Wordpress folder is located.
You could do that through the website's admin panel file manager or FTP access.

For example, the specific website could be located in something like `139.59.78.169/web/time_table/`

You could also use an `.htaccess` file in the root directory to point out the default webpage the IP address should redirect to.